# searching for clouds (in the sky) images big dataset

Tags: dataset

I'm looking for a big dataset of clouds (in the sky) ground based images. i need tens of thousands of images.

It is important that the images will be ground based and not from satellite/ flights.

I've tried to search and so far found datasets of hundreds/thousands of images, but not the amount I need.

I'll appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: You can search for a dataset using [Dataset Search](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/) or post a question on [OpenData.StackExchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). If the dataset is not found, try using pretrained models or data augmentation.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to using  Dataset Search, and will post the question on OpenData.StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could scrape Google, Bing, Yandex, Baidu for images and then do manual/semi-manual filtering of the data (semi with machine learning).  Google gives approximately 700 images, Yandex gives 1500. You could probably get about 10000 from the search systems.

Include search on Pinterest and Twitter. The feed of the last one was endless for me (probably more than 5000 photos, but you should check).

You could also make a crawler for Instagram and Facebook. Most likely Instagram could cover all your needs. But you need to check their license agreement. And the crawler is not so easy to program.